# How to get form value with "-" in name?

Tags: forms, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework (2.0.3) and I have this kind of form elements :

```
<input type="text" name="element-name" value="" />
```

Server side, I have a simple Form class :

```
public class MyForm {
    @Constraints.Required
    public String elementName;
}
```

of course, it doesn't work.

How can I do this? Are there annotations to indicate with name to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the same name in your HTML form:

  ```
  <input type="text" name="elementName" value="" />
  ```
- or use single-word names for your fields
- or bind it manually from the [DynamicForm](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html)

  ```
  String el = form().bindFromRequest().get("element-name");
  ```

Comment: So I *can not* use an element with "-" in a home made Form class ?

Comment: I didn't try, I don't see any good reason, while fixing HTML is fastest approach.

Comment: I can't change the HTML and I need to use a specific class, how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it's not possible.

I think you can use a [DynamicForm](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html) and do the validation yourself.

Or you can try something like this (do not know if it works):

```
Map<String, String> elementNameAsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
// find the HTML input value
elementNameAsMap.put("elementName", request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("element-name")[0]);

Form<MyForm> myForm = form(MyForm.class).bindFromRequest().bind(elementNameAsMap);
```